# Is "there results" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Can "there" be used with the verb "to result"? For example, in a mathematical text:

There results an isomorphism between pushouts in the category A.

Comment: Do you think the mathematical text is wrong?

Comment: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=there+results&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthere%20results%3B%2Cc0) shows that the pairing is often questionable, but there are numerous examples of perfectly valid usage.

Comment: There is potential confusion, because "results" has both mathematical and non-mathematical meanings.  But there's nothing wrong with the usage in general.  One simply needs to be wary of ambiguity-based confusion when writing about mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow 'there' with a verb, taking care to preserve number agreement - e.g. there comes a time; there exist many types of fruit; there result many variations in the construction of injectors; there results a compression of atheromatous material.

[There](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there)

Comment: It is fine in the sense that it is not grammatically wrong. However, I have racked my brain to think of any circumstance in a mathematical text in which the sentence quoted would be easier to understand than "An isomorphism between... results".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as Michael Harvey says in his answer, the example sentence is fine. For a more general account, see [McCawley's description](https://books.google.com/books?id=k6-C5AWWqjQC&q=there-insertion#v=snippet&q=there-insertion&f=false).